# Post Ajax call with json returning 400 whereas rest client works fine

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest, content-type

I am using jersey on the server side and my function uses

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response someFunction(SomeClass obj,@Context HttpServletRequest req){}
```

But when i make a http post call with content-type="application/json" and payload as `{"name":"abc","age":"20"}` from Advanced Rest Client, then the call will be a successfull call.
But if i create a client which makes an ajax call like,

```
 var person = {
            name: "abc",
            age:"20",
        }
 $.ajax({
    url: 'someUrl',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    },
    data: person
    });
```

Then this call will return 400 bad request and it is not going inside the function at server side. If we pass person object in the form of a string like,

```
"{\"name\":\"abc\",\"\age":\"20\"}"
```

Then ajax call also return 200.
Any reason why it is happening?

Comment: you didn't send json to the server. `person` is an object, and jquery will of course turn that into a param string, not json, because that's what it does by default.

Comment: i m passing javascript object directly

Comment: yes, and that's the problem, as I have explained. a javascript object is **not** json.

Comment: You should set `processData: false`

Comment: `processData: false` will result in `[object Object]` being sent to the server, so, also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should stringify data.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'someUrl',
   type: 'post',
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (data) {
   },
   data: JSON.stringify(person)
});
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me , what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: Nothing, it just isn't useful. it doesn't provide any information that isn't already on the dupe question.